# For loop isn't filtering out keywords in series of pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

Here is mock data representing my dataframe:

```
Arkansa  4  McKissic Creek Rd       HVAC/Plumbing
Florida  0  1130 Birdie Hills Rd    Lawn Care
Missouri 3  1140 Birdie Hills Rd    Interiors
Texas.   2  11625 Rainbow Ridge     Electrical
```

Here is my script that is supposed to be selecting the entire row out of the original dataframe (bool_filtered_df) and appending into a list (which I later convert to its own dataframe) if the sub-vertical (column 4) is "Electrical", "Duct Cleaning", "Water Treatment", or "Appliance Repair" however it is not filtering out any that I can tell and I can't see why. Any help appreciated. Thanks!

```
for d in range(0, len(bool_filtered_df)):
    try:
        if "Electrical" or "Duct Cleaning" or "Water Treatment" or "Appliance Repair" in bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'][d]:
            Geneva_Trais.append(bool_filtered_df.iloc[d])
        else:
            print("Wrong Sub-Vert")
    except TypeError as t:
        print(t)
        continue
```

Answer (score 2):

This statement:

```
        if "Electrical" or "Duct Cleaning" or "Water Treatment" or "Appliance Repair" in bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'][d]:
```

is interpreted as:

```
        if ("Electrical") or ("Duct Cleaning") or ("Water Treatment") or ("Appliance Repair" in bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'][d]):
```

Since "Electrical" is true, the if statement will always be true.  You can try this:

```
    if bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'][d] in ('Electrical', 'Duct Cleaning', 'Water Treatment', 'Appliance Repair'):
```

Comment: Good tip about the "`or` gotcha". But the version with `in` won't work; it will always be `False`, because `bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'][d]` will of course never be an element of that tuple. See [G. Anderson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384288/2954547) for a version that does what you were trying to do.

Comment: @Tim Roberts. Thank you for clarifying this for me!

Answer (score 2):

You can use built-in boolean filtering with [Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html)

```
bool_filtered_df[bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'].isin(['Electrical', 'Duct Cleaning', 'Water Treatment', 'Appliance Repair'])]
```

Comment: thank you for this! So this would be used if I do need an exact match?

Comment: Yes. If you had a longer string and you wanted to check if it contained keywords, you could use [Series.str.contains()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) as in `bool_filtered_df[bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'].str.conatins(r'Electrical|Duct Cleaning|Water Treatment|Appliance Repair')]`

Answer (score 0):

### Fixing the original problem

[Tim Roberts described](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384278/2954547) the problem.

This is sometimes called the "`or` gotcha". It is tempting for beginners to forget that Python is a programming language with strict rules, so they guess incorrectly at syntax that resembles English writing. This is one such incorrect guess.

One correct translation of your code would be:

```py
Geneva_Trais = []
for d in range(0, len(bool_filtered_df)):
    sub_vert = bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'].iloc[d]
    if (
        "Electrical" in sub_vert or
        "Duct Cleaning" in sub_vert or
        "Water Treatment" in sub_vert or
        "Appliance Repair" in sub_vert
    ):
        Geneva_Trais.append(bool_filtered_df.iloc[d])
    else:
        print(f"Wrong Sub-Vert: {idx}, {sub_vert}")
```

Note that you were mixing `[]` and `.iloc[]` in your original code as well, which is a *very* bad idea. `[]` on a Series is equivalent to `.loc[]`, which is only equivalent to `.iloc[]` in very specific circusmtances. These circumstances happen to be the default, so newbies tend to gloss over the very important distinction.

### Looping more efficiently

You can also loop over elements of a Series without using `.iloc` at each iteration, which is both faster and tidier-looking:

```py
Geneva_Trais = []
for idx, sub_vert in bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'].items():
    if (
        ("Electrical" in sub_vert) or
        ("Duct Cleaning" in sub_vert) or
        ("Water Treatment" in sub_vert) or
        ("Appliance Repair" in sub_vert)
    ):
        Geneva_Trais.append(bool_filtered_df.loc[idx])
    else:
        print(f"Wrong Sub-Vert: {idx}, {sub_vert}")
```

### G. Anderson's loop-less approximation

If it makes sense to compare these strings exactly, with `==`, then we can use the `isin` method as described in [G. Anderson's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69384288/2954547) and avoid looping entirely:

```py
sub_verts = [
    'Electrical', 'Duct Cleaning', 'Water Treatment', 'Appliance Repair'
]

Geneva_Trais = bool_filtered_df.loc[
    bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'].isin(sub_verts)
]
```

Based on the sample data you provided, this might have been your intention.

This technique also returns a DataFrame, not a list of Series.

Note that I personally prefer using `.loc[]` and not `[]` for Boolean subsetting of rows. I only use `[]` for selecting columns by name. This is to avoid selecting the wrong thing by mistake.

### An exact loop-less translation

**However**, your original code does not have the same behavior as the `.isin` technique. Your code checks if each of the 4 strings is a *sub-string* of the value in the Series. The correct loop-less translation of your code would be:

```py
def check_sub_vert(sub_vert):
    return (
        "Electrical" in sub_vert or
        "Duct Cleaning" in sub_vert or
        "Water Treatment" in sub_vert or
        "Appliance Repair" in sub_vert
    )

is_ok = bool_filtered_df['Sub-Vertical'].apply(check_sub_vert)
Geneva_Trais = bool_filtered_df.loc[is_ok]
```

The 4 `in` checks are still there, but we have moved them to a separate function. We can use `.apply` to gather the results of calling this function on each element, without using a `for` loop. This can be *much* faster than the loop in many cases, and in general is the preferred style of using Pandas. Sometimes this style is called "vectorized".

Comment: @shadowwalker Thank you so much for such a thorough lesson. I especially appreciate the warning about using iloc[] with [] as well the explanation of tidying up  the code and eliminating the need to use iloc at each iteration. Extremely Helpful!